# Function pointer not working

Tags: c++

This code is not working

any idea why

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include "a.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    boost::asio::io_service io;
  std::cout << "Wait for five seconds\n";
     boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
   //  t.wait();
     A *vvv=new A();
     std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
     t.async_wait(&print);
         std::cout << "Keep cool and wait!\n";
    return a.exec();
}
void  print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "You are cool!\n";
}
```

Error:

> D:\qtsrc\asiotry\main.cpp:14: error: C2065: 'print' : undeclared
>   identifier

Comment: add `void  print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/);` before main()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this code:

```
 int *address = &i; //using i here!

 int i; //declaration
```

**What is wrong with this code?**  You're doing something similar.

Declare `print` before `main()` so you can *use* it in `main()`:

```
//declaration
void  print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/);

int main()
{
     //use print here
}

//definition
void  print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)  
{
    std::cout << "You are cool!\n";
}
```

---

Note that all you're required to declare the function *before* its usage, that **does not necessarily mean** that the declaration must  be above `main()`. You could as well do this also:

```
int main()
{
      //declaration
      void  print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/);

     //use print here AFTER the declaration!
}
```

Hope that helps you to understand the concept of declaration and usage. -)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you use `print` in the `async_wait` call, it's not declared yet, so it doesn't know what `print` is.

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Move the definition of the `print` function to above `main`.
2. Before using it, declare it as a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Remember one thing. The **declaration** of a function should precede its **reference**(usage) in the program.

Either add this before main:-

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/);
```

**OR**

Define the function before main.